# Deploy and update Django Project while Server is running

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, server

So I have a **Django Project**. Now I want to publish it but I have a few questions without answeres:

Normally if I want to make a change at my **Django Project** the Server needs to reload:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 12, 2021 - 21:07:20
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'Project.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.3 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

If I want to change a running Server it will be stopped a few (Milli)seconds. Is this a bad behavior or is it the normal way to do it? :)

Comment: It is the normal way. It is normal for every kind of program.

Comment: To add to Sırrı's answer, some services will spin up instances using the new code then swap them for the old instances giving you zero downtime for a deployment.

Comment: @schillingt I did not know that. New day new things to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! @SırrıKırımlıoğlu and schillingt. Just post your answere as an command and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the normal way. The normal way for every kind of program mostly.